# C++ inheritance issue error C2084 function already has a body

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, compiler-errors, parent-child

I got the following code in c++...

If I remove the inheritance from Actor everything is fine.

I tried looking up the issue and found similar issues but nothing fixed this. 
I have cleaned and rebuilt the project few times as well. This is probably just a silly mistake somewhere that I just cant find...

Duke.h

```
#pragma once

#include "cocos2d.h"
#include <string.h>
#include "Actor.h"
#include "HelloWorldScene.h"
#include "AssetManager.h"

class Duke : public Actor {

private:
    AssetManager* assets;
public:

    Duke() :Actor() {};
    ~Duke();
    void update(float) override;
    virtual bool init() override;

};
```

Duke.cpp

```
#include "Duke.h"
#include "cocos2d.h"



Duke::Duke() {}

Duke::~Duke()
{
}
void Duke::update(float)
{
}

bool Duke::init()
{
    return false;
}
```

It is a really simple class that I just created, however I get this error about a functions (that I do not believe exists even) and I am really clueless by now...

```
2>------ Build started: Project: MyCppGame, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
2>Duke.cpp
2>g:\cpp\projects\corgi\mycppgame\classes\duke.cpp(6): error C2084: function 'Duke::Duke(void)' already has a body
2>g:\cpp\projects\corgi\mycppgame\classes\duke.h(15): note: see previous definition of '{ctor}'
2>Done building project "MyCppGame.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 4 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

(if needed, here is the Actor class decleration)

Actor.h

```
#pragma once

#include "cocos2d.h"
#include <string.h>
USING_NS_CC;
class Actor : public cocos2d::Node {
private:
    Sprite* spr;
public:
    Actor(std::string*);

    Actor();

    ~Actor();

};
```

Actor.cpp

```
#include "Actor.h"
#include "cocos2d.h"
#include <string>
USING_NS_CC;
Actor::Actor(std::string* str)
{
    spr = Sprite::createWithSpriteFrameName(*str);
    this->addChild(spr);
    this->setPosition(Vec2(100, 100));
    this->setScale(4);
    Texture2D::TexParams texParams = { GL_NEAREST, GL_NEAREST, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE };
    spr->getTexture()->setTexParameters(texParams);
}


Actor::Actor()
{
}

Actor::~Actor()
{
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at your `Duke` constructor. You have it *defined* (implemented with a function body) in both the header file and the source file.

Either remove it completely from the source file. Or remove the curly-braces `{}` from the header file.

Comment: wow that was fairly simple, i removed the function from my definition from my .h file and moved the `:actor()` portion to my .cpp deceleration which I didn't figure had to have that... well now I know, thanks!